# Scala Compile Error

Tags: scala

I have trouble in building the following code:

```
type graph_t = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Long, (Long, Float)];
var graph : graph_t = graph_t();
```

However, it does work by replacing the graph_t() with the original type:

```
var graph : graph_t = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Long, (Long, Float)] ();
```

Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala knows two namespaces: types and values. Types define what values are capable of, and values are the things you call methods on.

`graph_t()` is a method call (the `apply` method), but you did not define a value called `graph_t`, you defined a type called `graph_t`, and you cannot call methods on types.

The reason `scala.collection.mutable.Map[Long, (Long, Float)] ()` works is because `scala.collection.mutable.Map` is both a type and a value.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting.  Try this:

```
type s = String;
var x = s()
```

You get the same error: not found.

That's is because the name of the class is both the name of the type and the name of the constructor, but the name of a type is not necessarily the name of a constructor.

In this case, the function Map actually constructs a concrete implementation of the Map abstract class.